# Bootstrap navbar moves right on scroll

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, dygraphs

The navbar should stick to the left and right edges.

However, when I scroll the page a little more, the navbar moves right as in the second screenshot. The problem start happening on scroll when the `<div class="row" id="myDyGraph">` (ie. following graph div) crosses the narbar.

This is happening only for Chrome, could be a bootstrap 3 bug?

For the background, I am using BS3 and Dygraph. The issue is happening only when dyGraph is initialized. If I skip dygraph-div rendering, it works fine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Fiddle or some code?  You have a margin on the left messing with something.

Comment: Post your code on fiddle for inspection