# Bootstrap navbar moves when I change to another section

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, padding

I made my first Wordpress for learning purposes. I have downloaded Themekraft, and I added my own customized bootstrap header navbar, because I want to customize as much as I can.

I have some sections (only "inicio" and "articulos" are working), but when there is an article with photo (sometimes without photo happens the same), I have realised that blue navbar moves.

I tried to fix it in many different ways (adding a max width for the body 
and navbar, deleting a lot of margins and/or paddings...), but I have only discovered that it is a problem of paddings... I think.

I mean, when I add, for example, a padding-top:10px for the body, everything seems to be ok... until I have an article or two. When it happens, it seems i have to add more padding-top on the body in order to "fix" the problem.

I have searched on SO suggestions, looking for some clues, but I found nothing.

[Bootstrap navbar moves right on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787345/bootstrap-navbar-moves-right-on-scroll)

[Bootstrap navbar covers top of section when linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699281/bootstrap-navbar-covers-top-of-section-when-linked)

What could I do? I have uploaded the site to a server so you can check it.

http://pruebaint.esy.es/

Comment: Please provide some specific code and/or specific steps to reproduce the issue on the link you posted. Just posting a link to your site is not the best way to get any meaningful answers. I'm unable to understand/see the problem on the link you posted and without more information, it is unlikely anyone will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I can´t see where in my code is the problem. I figured out that it is a padding problem buy maybe it is something related to scroll like @Ankur Agarwal says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see it the issue is not any of your padding. Its the scroll bar that is causing the problem as the content moves somewhat to the left. If your page has lesser content without vertical scrolls you will not see the nav moving.

Is there any other problem that you see apart from horizontal movement?

Comment: Maybe you are right, no i haven´t seen any other problem. Isn´t it a real issue then @Ankur Agarwal?